# Gson, can't serialize/deserialize class type

Tags: java, gson

I've got a class like this:

```
public class A {
    @serializedName("type")
    Class<?> type;
...
}
```

But when I tried to serialize it I get an error saying "Attempt to serialize java.lang.class: java.lang.String. Forgot to register a TypeAdapter?". So I created this adapter:

```
public class MyTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Class> {
public Class read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
    } else {
        String className = in.nextString();
        try {
            return Class.forName(className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException("class " + className + " not found");
        }
    }
}

public void write(JsonWriter out, Class value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
        out.nullValue();
    } else {
        out.value(value.getName());
    }
}
```

}

And registered it like this:

```
new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Class.class, new MyTypeAdapter ()).create().
fromJson(value, listType);
```

But I'm still getting the same error.
What am I doing wrong?
Does the implementation of the adapter look ok?

Comment: Is it `JsonClassTypeAdapter` or `MyTypeAdapter`?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, fixed.

Comment: The error seems to be unrelated to what you're doing. `fromJson` should've produced a deserialize error, not a serialize error. Also, weird that it is showing error for String and not Class (String has built-in typeadapter). Can you provide a MCVE that replicates the issue?

Comment: Note that doing `Class.forName()` in a deserializer is a potentially *huge* security bug: you're basically giving the JSON file permission to execute somewhat arbitrary code in your application.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

Gson takes type information into account: you're trying to mix `Class` and `Class<?>` that are different *types* representing a raw type and a wildcard-parameterized type respectively.
From this perspective, Gson does not consider `Class` (found in your `registerTypeAdapter`) and `Class<?>` (found in your DTOs) equivalent.
For this case you have to register the type hierarchy adapter with `registerTypeHierarchyAdapter`.

> Does the implementation of the adapter look ok?

Yes, but it can be improved slightly:

```java
final class ClassTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<Class<?>> {

    // The type adapter does not hold state, so it can be easily made singleton (+ making the constructor private)
    private static final TypeAdapter<Class<?>> instance = new ClassTypeAdapter()
            // This is a convenient method that can do trivial null-checks in write(...)/read(...) itself
            .nullSafe();

    private ClassTypeAdapter() {
    }

    static TypeAdapter<Class<?>> get() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Class<?> value)
            throws IOException {
        // value is never a null here
        out.value(value.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            // This will never be a null since nullSafe() is used above
            final String className = in.nextString();
            return Class.forName(className);
        } catch ( final ClassNotFoundException ex ) {
            // No need to duplicate the message generated in ClassNotFoundException
            throw new JsonParseException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

As it's [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738851/gson-cant-serialize-deserialize-class-type#comment86496013_49738851) by [@Daniel Pryden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128397/daniel-pryden), this is potentially a huge security issue, because `Class.forName` may execute code (static initializers).
You should check the `className` against the classes whitelist before `Class.forName(...)` is executed.
Also note that `Class` instances do not hold type parameterization (please see what `TypeToken`s and `ParameterizedType`s are for) and you might want to encode the type with all of its type parameterization (easy to `toString(...)` but not that easy to parse though - I faced such an issue once and resolved it by implementing a parser in JParsec).